# How to ajax post to a re-written url?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Currently I'm submitting a form via post to a PHP file, the only problem.. is that I can't submit to that php file because something is going wrong with ajax. My question is can I submit to a different URL if the backend has rewritten urls?

CURRENT PAGE URL:
 - actual: http://site.com/topic.php?id=1
 - re-written: http://site.com/topic/1

WANTED PAGE URL:
 - actual: http://site.com/comment.php

how can I send to the comment.php file? I think javascript assumes I'm trying to do site.com/topic/comment.php

HTML:

```
            <form id="comment_on_topic" onsubmit="return sendComment();">
            <textarea id="topicreply" name="topicreply">Initial value.</textarea>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
```

Javascript:

```
function sendComment(){
        var $form = $('#comment_on_topic');
        var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");
        var serializedData = $form.serialize();
        $inputs.prop("disabled", true);
        /* GET FORM INPUTS & SERIALIZE */

        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http.open("POST", '/comment.php');
        http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        http.send(serializedData);
        /* AJAX REQUEST TO POST TO FILE */

        return false;
    }
```

PHP: //not being executed at all.. (in comment.php)

```
    <?php if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") : ?>
<?php
    require_once 'protected/connect.inc.php';
    require_once 'protected/functions.inc.php';


    $comment = sanitize($_POST['topicreply']);

    sendComment( 1, 1, "Topic Reply", $comment );
?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and yes the javascript is being executed. Serialized data looks good ("id=value&anotherid=value")

Comment: what is your rewrite / routing code?

Comment: That depends on how your re-write rules are written, what are your re-write rules? If the rules redirect ALL requests to topic.php then you need to create a rule that redirects to comment.php, if they redirect /anyword to /anyword.php, then you can replace /comment.php with /comment/ and it should work! It does not matter to AJAX whether the URL is re-written or not, in the matter of fact it actually does not know what's happening on the server, so what do you have to type in the URL to reach comment.php? you can figure that out by reading your .htaccess or wherever the re-write rules are

Comment: rewrite "/topic/([0-9]{1,10})" /topic.php?id=$1 last;

Comment: It would probably be better to append the relevant pieces of code to the question

Comment: That's all there @ThomWiggers

Comment: Don't you have a `.htaccess`-like file with rewrite rules? Otherwise it would load the file.

Comment: @ThomWiggers It's nginx, not apache. No need for .htaccess

Comment: That's why I said "-like" :) Do you really have no other rewrite stuff? Because then the `comments.php` file in the public root of the webserver should be executed...

Comment: @ThomWiggers well all file.php files are accessed via site.com/file, but it can also be executed via site.com/file.php. I'm so confused. The ajax isn't executing comment.php on root :/

Comment: What does the ajax call return to the browser? Use the developer console in the browser to find out the XHR call info.

Comment: @ThomWiggers how can you check that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40226/discussion-between-thom-wiggers-and-jakes625)

Answer (score 0):

To understand what happens, I'd suggest :
- to look at Apache logs (both access and error) to see if your URL is rewritten and how it is rewritten.
- to run you query manualy from a browser or from a tool like Chrome plugin Postman (you can see PHP error then).

This should help to spot the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the issue. I had to use http.open( "POST", '../comment.php' ); javascript/html/css does not pickup on the actual filepath such as php. (just future help for anyone else)